# VS Code debug stops at vm.js in createScript function

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I am getting a strange issue with Microsoft Visual Studio Code.

I am trying to debug my project's **nodejs** script and it always stops at a system file **vm.js** in **createScript** function.

It doesn't go to next debug point of my script if I click on **Continue** button. Why is that? I have updated/removed/reinstalled the VS Code but no help!

[image]

I tried it after deleting **node_modules** folder but still getting the same issue.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Does it still happen after you explicitly remove all breakpoints (`Debug -> Remove All Breakpoints`)?

Comment: Have you checked 'All Exceptions' or 'Uncaught exceptions" in the debugger breakpoint window?

Answer (score 0):

Strange but it is automatically fixed after upgrading the mac os version from Yosemite to Mojave.